# log4net one file per run

Tags: log4net

I need my application to create a log file each time it runs.

My preferred format would be **App.log.yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss**. If that's not possible, I'd settle for **App.log.yyyy-MM-dd.counter**

This is my current appender configuration:

```xml
<appender name="File" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="App.log"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
  <datePattern value=".yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"/>
  <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
</appender>
```

But it creates a random number of files based on the date and time.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I assume that the application should create only one log file every time it runs, so you do not need a rolling file appender (though my solution would apply for rolling file appenders as well):

```xml
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="c:\temp\App-%date{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%2thread] %-5level - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

(Obviously you can use other your own layout and other settings for the file appender.)

Comment: That did the trick. I didn't know about PatternString. Thanks!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this will create unlimited number of log files, where as the rollingstyle=Once solution will handle the purging of old files automatically.  I think that solution is better.

Comment: I guess you are right. I cannot remember if "rollingstyle=once" was possible when I gave my answer...

Answer (score 40):

Also note that you can set your rolling style as

`rollingstyle="Once"`

and it will create a new file every time it is run. If `staticLogFileName` is set to true (e.g., `logname.log`) the previous logs will be set to `logname.log.1`, `logname.log.2`, etc.

The number of files kept before overwriting the oldest (say, 10) can be controlled by setting

`maxSizeRollBackups="10"`

**Edit:**
My config, which creates a datestamped log per execution (unless one exists, in which case it follows the `.1` rule, looks like this:

```xml
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Logs\MyLog-%date{dd-MM-yyyy}.log" />
    <appendToFile value="false" />    
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" /> <!--infinite-->
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Once" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5level %date [%thread] %c{1} - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Not 100% sure if I need `appendToFile="false"` as [the docs](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/P_log4net_Appender_RollingFileAppender_RollingStyle.htm) say that's done automatically when you use `rollingStyle="Once"`, but this makes it clearer in any case.

Comment: I have applied your way and it does create the log file with date time. But when I try to run same `api` again it adds the new logs into the current log file.

Answer (score 1):

It's documented from apache in the log4net docs at:

https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html

ctrl+f for "per program execution"

```
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="logfile.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="false" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
    <maximumFileSize value="50GB" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```