# Log4net sometimes creating two logs, one empty

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-appender, fileappender

Using the below configuration, about half of the time, I'm getting two logs per one, one empty.  They differ in filename by one second (log.2015-03-09_11-50-25 vs log.2015-03-09_11-50-26)

I'm trying to have one log per run of the console application.

```
<log4net>

  <appender name="Log" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\env\QA\Logs\consoleapp\log.%date{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.txt"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date    %message%newline"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="Log"/>
  </root>
</log4net>
```

The latter log is the only one that's populated/written to.

Why is this happening?  How do I fix it?

EDIT: Turns out i was instantiating a second logger in my code. When the instantiation occurred during a different second, a second log was created. The appender was working correctly.

Comment: remove the second specifier in the filename.

Comment: your approch may be suboptimal. Try using username/pid/something else beeing unique to a time period small enough for your logs as "primary key" of you log-file-naming

Comment: @swe timestamp is good for logfile names - allows easily readable filenames and places them in context.

Comment: Turns out i was instantiating a second logger in my code.  When the instantiation occurred during a different second, a second log was created.  The appender was working correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen something similar before - it's due to the second being specified in the filename, and the writes are occuring during the end of one second and the start of another.

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\env\QA\Logs\consoleapp\log.%date{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.txt"/>
```

should be

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\env\QA\Logs\consoleapp\log.%date{yyyy-MM-dd}.txt"/>
```

In my last job, somebody set the second specifier in the log file name, and the production server came close to crashing trying the render the 150,000 files contained in the log folder.

Edit:

If you want to write once per run, you can add the following to your log4net configuration:

```
<rollingStyle value="Once" />
```

and you *might* need to set the `appendToFile` attribute to be false.

[log4net one file per run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048844/log4net-one-file-per-run)

so your config would look like this:

```
<appender name="Log" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\env\QA\Logs\consoleapp\log.%date{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.txt"/>
    <appendToFile value="false" />    
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" /> <!--infinite-->
    <rollingStyle value="Once" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date    %message%newline"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
```

Comment: I don't want to overwrite or append to the previous log.  I want a separate file for each run.  Your suggestion causes the log to be appended to if it falls in the same day.

Comment: Same problem as my original post, but noticed when the second file is in the same second, it still creates two, one with a ".1" appended to the filename

Answer (score 1):

I used user1666620's solution, but still got a .log.1 file. 
Turns out I had the following line in my **AssemblyInfo.cs** file:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

**Removing** the above line fixed my issue. By the way, my *program.cs* looks like:

```
public static class Program
{
    static Program()
    {
        // Initialize logging
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    }

    private static readonly ILog log =
        LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    ...
}
```