# New file for each message with log4net

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

I'm using log4net to trace application errors and debugging information, all of that goes into one big file and is working fine.

But I'm also want to create a separate log4net appender which will be used to dump incoming messages to disk. These will be in a separate directory and I want each call to `log.Info` to be written to a new file, preferably with a timestamp in the filename.

That way I can easily bring up the specific message that was sent to my component at a given timestamp.

Can this be done through configuration?

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048844/log4net-one-file-per-run

Comment: The difference is that I want a new log file on each call to log.Info, the linked questions/answer is about a new file er run. You need to restart the application to get a new file if using the method in the linked question/answer. But I cannot restart the app every time...

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
private void LogFile(string logFileName, string message, Exception ex)
{
    log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["Version"] = "1";
    log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogName"] = logFileName;

    ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger("DeIdentifyDicom");

    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

    if (ex != null)
    {
        logger.Fatal(message, ex);
    }
    else
    {
        logger.Fatal(message);
    }
}
```

[how do I define log file at run time?](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4net-user/201007.mbox/%3C26594B7EA4A52642BFB6A002836DE21904DC127D@VHAV21MSGA2.v21.med.va.gov%3E)

Comment: It sounded promising but I can't get it to work. Will make another try tomorrow!

Comment: You would have to set the LogName property and call `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` between every log call. It would be more efficient just to load the target appender and change the file name programatically.