# Logging actions, recreating the log file

Tags: c#, winforms, logging

How recreate log file instead of append?

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="Logs\Example.log"/>
      <param name="Create" value="true"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="5MB"/>
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d  %-5p %m%n"/>
      </layout>

    </appender>

    <logger name="LOGGER">
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender"/>
    </logger>
  </log4net>
```

Create and CreateNew did not work here `<param name="Create" value="true"/>`

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking, can you clarify?

Comment: @maccettura, recreate the log file) not append

Comment: Have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048844/log4net-one-file-per-run. It seems to be your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try RollingFileAppender.RollingStyle Property